# Rich Notification service extension with multiple SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, push-notification, clevertap

Rich notificaion  I have two SDKs in my react-native project for notification(CleverTap & Firebase). Simple notification is working fine with  both SDKs, but there is issue with the rich notification, only one rich notification is working fine as per the document of firebase and Clevertap. in simple word I want to render rich notification with single service extension.

**Note:- Both SDK has different notification payload.**

I have added one Service extension as per the RNFirebase doc.
https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images

Firebase notification working fine but now issue with Clevertap rich notification because, Clevertap has different set-up and payload.
https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/rich-push-notifications